# Is it possible to browse a WSL file system that WAS running on another hard drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I *had* WSL running on an old hard drive. Now I *have* a different WSL instance running on a new hard drive.  I'd like to copy a script I created on the old HD/WSL, but I'm not sure where the WSL data is kept, and ideally, there would be a way to access the FS without booting up the old WSL.

Is there a way to do this without booting up the old WSL install? If not, how do I run the old WSL installation without clobbering the current one?

I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a duplicate as it's about WSL1 and I'm using WSL2. I'll try the answer and see if it still works. Thanks.